# How can I fetch stock price at a given time on a certain date?

Tags: api, stocks, trading, stockquotes

I've found a lot of historical price APIs for fetching stock price for a given date. But haven't been successful in finding any API to provide price at certain time on a given date. Like price of GOOG on 08/02/2017 at 3:55PM - How do I find this?

Comment: Were you able to do this?